# How are tuples handled for the function selector?

Tags: solidity, signature, abi

How are tuple types encoded into the function signature to generate the 4 byte function selector? [The official specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html) doesn't state anything for tuple types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `(type1,type2,...)` to represent structs.

For example, the `fillOrder` function in [0x 2.0](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4f833a24e1f95d70f028921e27040ca56e09ab0b#code):

```
function fillOrder(
    Order memory order,
    uint256 takerAssetFillAmount,
    bytes memory signature
)
    public
    returns (LibFillResults.FillResults memory fillResults);

struct Order {
    address makerAddress;           // Address that created the order.      
    address takerAddress;           // Address that is allowed to fill the order. If set to 0, any address is allowed to fill the order.          
    address feeRecipientAddress;    // Address that will recieve fees when order is filled.      
    address senderAddress;          // Address that is allowed to call Exchange contract methods that affect this order. If set to 0, any address is allowed to call these methods.
    uint256 makerAssetAmount;       // Amount of makerAsset being offered by maker. Must be greater than 0.        
    uint256 takerAssetAmount;       // Amount of takerAsset being bid on by maker. Must be greater than 0.        
    uint256 makerFee;               // Amount of ZRX paid to feeRecipient by maker when order is filled. If set to 0, no transfer of ZRX from maker to feeRecipient will be attempted.
    uint256 takerFee;               // Amount of ZRX paid to feeRecipient by taker when order is filled. If set to 0, no transfer of ZRX from taker to feeRecipient will be attempted.
    uint256 expirationTimeSeconds;  // Timestamp in seconds at which order expires.          
    uint256 salt;                   // Arbitrary number to facilitate uniqueness of the order's hash.     
    bytes makerAssetData;           // Encoded data that can be decoded by a specified proxy contract when transferring makerAsset. The last byte references the id of this proxy.
    bytes takerAssetData;           // Encoded data that can be decoded by a specified proxy contract when transferring takerAsset. The last byte references the id of this proxy.
}
```

The function selector is calculated using:

`fillOrder((address,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,bytes,bytes),uint256,bytes)`

This produces a keccak256 of: `b4be83d519a652e54a6073d7e55643f575508112b09dcc74264b807477b576c5`, and the first 4 bytes are: `b4be83d5`

You can confirm this by looking at this tx which called fillOrder: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4811b7492bd845a46a052b063f943c4760174e932cb171ca25a934de6e7e4da4