# Method with struct not presented over Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, struct, function-selector

In my smart contract I have some methods that get a struct as an input:

```
contract MyContract {

  MyStruct {
    uint[] arr;
    address[] addresses; 
  }

  function myFunction(MyStruct[] structs) external {
  }
}
```

I called this function and on Etherscan although my contract is verified it seems to show the function selector (first 4 bytes of the encoded function signature) and not the function name.
Is there a way to overcome this and show the function name?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

---

Following [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/60875/37689) I have managed to match between my function signature and the right function selector.
As far as I understood from the [documentation I should be able to use the method-registry](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-function-names.html#using-eth-method-registry) contract in order to register my method.

I have registered my function over the [SignatureReg contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x44691b39d1a75dc4e0a0346cbb15e310e6ed1e86) but  I can't see any change in the names of the functions over etherscan. I was expecting etherscan to listen to this contract (or to query it) and update the method name accordingly once it is registered but I guess this is not how this things work.
Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for the moment this is a known issue of Etherscan, it is mentioned in [their tweeter page](https://twitter.com/etherscan/with_replies).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are the step by steps from the metamask documentation:

1. Go to the Mainnet Parity signature registration contract on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x44691b39d1a75dc4e0a0346cbb15e310e6ed1e86#writeContract)
2. Connect MetaMask
3. Use etherscan's write contract feature to input the string value (without quotes or spaces) to the register function (0x59708645)

For example:

getOwners()

`execTransaction(address,uint256,bytes,uint8,uint256,uint256,uint256,address,address,bytes)`

Click `"write"`

Approve the transaction in MetaMask (you only pay gas)

Comment: Ok did it, still no change.

Answer (score 2):

Function name will appear if you upload your contract source code to Etherscan, or if it recognizes the 4 byte signature.

In case you only want Etherscan to recognize the method signature, you can add it on the [Verified Signatures](https://etherscan.io/verifiedSignatures#) page, connect your MetaMask wallet and use the **Verify Signature** option.

You can verify your contract code using [Etherscan's Verify & Publish](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract) page, follow the questions and upload your code accordingly, function name should appear on the tx details thereafter.

If you're using Hardhat, it's very simple, follow this [guide](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan) to verify your contract in Etherscan, once it's verified the function name should appear.

Comment: My contract is verified on etherscan. Standard functions that do not get structs as input params are recognized well but functions that get structs as input params are not.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the Verify Signature option?